# Should I convert variables that don't have units into a z-score

Tags: regression

In the regression analysis, some variables don't have units. How to interpret the coefficients of such variables? Should I convert them into z z-score before run regress? Should converting be done after taking log of variables? I'm quite new to regression and hope someone can help me.

Comment: What do you mean by variables that don't have units...?

Comment: dollar, meter，degree celsius，etc

Comment: dollars, meters and degrees _are_ units...
As in - "An increase of a thousand dollars in salary, controlling all other variables, is significantly associated with an increase of 10 square meters in house size"

Comment: I mean variables don't have units, such those generated regressors.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In a regression model the expectation of a response, $\mathbb{E}[Y]$, is equated to a linear combination of variable values $x_i$ with coefficients $\beta_i$:

$$\mathbb{E}[Y] = \cdots + \beta_i x_i + \cdots$$

If the units in which $Y$ is expressed are, for example, "meters", then its expectation will have the same units.  If the units in which $x_i$ is expressed are, for example, "hours", then this relationship can be more fully written as

$$\mathbb{E}[Y]\,\left(\text{meters}\right) =  \cdots + \beta_i x_i\,\left(\text{hours}\right) + \cdots$$

For this to make sense, it is necessary that the units of $\beta_i$ be meters per hour:

$$\mathbb{E}[Y]\,\left(\text{meters}\right) =  \cdots + \beta_i \left(\frac{\text{meters}}{\text{hour}}\right)x_i\,\left(\text{hours}\right) + \cdots$$

The roles of "meters" and "hours" may be replaced by any units whatsoever, demonstrating a general conclusion:

> The units of the coefficients in a linear regression model are the units of the response *per* (that is, divided by) the units of the corresponding regressors.

*This holds even for variables that are unitless.*  For instance, if $x_i$ is a pure number (such as a fraction or a logarithm), then $\beta_i$ must have the same units as $Y$.  If both $x_i$ and $Y$ are logarithms, then $\beta_i$ is unitless.

Comment: +1. There is an excellent paper by Finney on dimensions and statistics. It seems puzzling to me that many people using statistics won't think in terms of units and dimensions, unless they never studied science in high school at all. The reference is accessible at https://www.jstor.org/stable/2346969 and the full text will be accessible to many from there too (although not all).